# Призрение и презрение — разница

Tags: этимология, словообразование

"Призрение" — это забота, опека. Дома призрения — благотворительные заведения, где заботились о больных и неимущих. "Презрение" — прямо противоположное: высокомерие пополам с неприязнью.
Не знаю, как точнее сформулировать вопрос. Но вот как тут приставка влияет на смысл?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я думаю, что здесь происхождение у слов совершенно разное. 
Давайте рассмотрим слово "*презрение*". Оно обозначает состояние, в котором кто-то кого-либо *презирает*. Причем можно просто *презирать* (несов.), а мож *презреть* (сов.). Мне кажется, что здесь налицо чередование или беглая гласная. И мне кажется совершенно явным, что корень этих слов к корню слова *призрение* никакого отношения не имеет. Ведь **при**зрение - это по сути **при**глядывание за кем-либо, присмотр. Однокоренные - *призреть*, *призревать* и, я бы еще добавил, - *зрение*.

Comment: " **Призреть**
Это заимствованное из
старославянского языка слово,
имеющее значение "дать кому-либо
приют и пропитание", было
образовано приставочным способом
от **зьръти** – "смотреть, наблюдать""  " **Презирать**
Это заимствованное из
старославянского языка слово
образовано приставочным способом
от глагола зирати (**зьръти**) и
буквально означало "смотреть
сверху вниз". (Этим. словарь Крылова) Жду комментария, в чем разница между "двумя разными" корнями. **Зри в корень"**, уважаемый оценщик и приемщик ответа!)))))))

Comment: @gecube, объясните, какой "другой корень" в слове *презреть*?? Источник, значение корня, однокоренные слова, пожалуйста, если не трудно. Утверждение Вы не доказали никоим образом.

Comment: Если не слабо, удалите свой невразумительный ответ (в части рассуждений о слове *презреть*) и напишите другой, обоснованный ссылками на этимологические словари.

Comment: @grumant, подтвердите лучше свою точку зрения касательно корней словарями. Еще раз повторюсь, что одно дело как корень выделяется в современных словах по современным нормативам, а другое дело - происхождение слова и, скажем так, исторический морфологический разбор. Сравните ситуацию в соседнем вопросе со словом "вынуть".

Comment: @grumant, касательно слов "презорливый, презоравый, презорливость, презорник, презритель" - спасибо, действительно интересно. Другой вопрос, что они отдают стариной. Ни разу не видел их использования в современных текстах.

Comment: Спасибо, что отписались. Аргументов Вашего особого мнения по поводу значения корня *зьре* в слове *презреть* я не нашел. Вы проиграли наш маленький спор. Надеюсь, Вы это понимаете))) Удалите свой ответ!

Answer (score 1):

Приставка "пре"  обозначает действие, проявляющееся в высокой степени (преисполниться, превозносить, преуспевать), а также, обозначает чрезмерность, выход за пределы чего-нибудь (превысить, пресытиться, переизбыток). А это современное слово "сверх". Следовательно, *презирать* - значит *смотреть свысока*.

Приставка "при" имеет значение близости, непосредственного примыкания к чему-нибудь, приближения, добавления, доведения действия до определенного результата.

Таким образом, *призирать* - значит: находиться при ком-то, быть рядом, чтобы приносить пользу, смотреть за ребенком; ухаживать за больным, за гостем, вообще, заботиться о ком-то.

Answer (score 0):

Словарь Древнего Русского языка. Составленный по Остромирову Евангелiю. Ф. Миклошичу, А. X. Востокову, Я. И. Бередникову и I. С. Кочетову. Изданiе А.С. Суворина, 1899 (скан, потому прошу прощение есть искажение старо-славянских букв)

**презираемый** б. гл. быть пренебрегаему. — **презиратель** м. презирающій кого или что либо.— **презираем** пр. обращающий вниманіе, оставляющій безъ вниманія.

…

**презорливый** пр. презирающій другихъ, гордый, высокомерный.

**презорникъ** м. презритель.

**презорство** ср. гордость, высокомеріе, презорливость. — **презорствовать** гл. презирать, пренебрегать, высокомерствовать. — **презоръ** м. тоже, что въ 1 значеній **презорство, зазоръ, зазрение**.

**презрети** гл. презреть, презирать.

**презъ** прд. безъ.

**

**призирание** ср. осматриваніе, разсматриваніе. — **призиратель** м. призирающій другихъ — **призирати** гл. 1) смотреть, осматривать, разсматривать; 2) взирать долу, приникать съ высоты; 3) милосердовать, взыскивать, благоволить къ кому либо.

**призоръ** м. присмотръ, осматриваніе, изследованіе. — **призоръ очесъ** ("очей"??) м. порча отъ худаго глаза, обаятельное действіе недоброжелательнаго взгля-да. — **призорьнъ** пр. относящейся къ призору.

Из определения (**презъ** прд. безъ.) следует что "през" - это отрицание наличия чего-то "без", отсутствие. Если предположить что сдвоенная "зз" редуцировалась (преззрение, преззираемый), то следовательно, "презирать" - это не желать "зрить", "смотреть", "заботиться об этом". Сравните также "без-при-*зорник*" - т.е. без присмотра, без заботы - без **призора**. Говоря "я презираю", человек указывает, что на том, что он презирает нет его внимания, нет его заботы, нет его смотрения (зрения). Причем смотрения не только в физическом или физиологическом, как глядение глазами, но и ментального. Сравните, когда говорят "*Посмотри* на это с другой стороны...", т.е. предлагают другую ментальную точку *зрения*.

Самое интересное начинается дальше в использовании "презрения", например "посмотреть с презрением", т.е. посмотреть так, чтобы другой увидел или заметил, что я на него не смотрю. Это должно быть в моем смотрении на него - то, что я теперь снял с него то мое смотрение, которое было на нем раньше. Он больше не достоин этого моего смотрения, моей заботы.

Answer (score 0):

"Призри" употребляется часто в молитвах. Обычно по отношению к Богу: "Призри с небесе и виждь", т. е. прояви милость. Дом призрения — дом милосердия Бога к убогим людям. Дома призрения строились, как правило, с домовым храмом, чтобы слабые и больные имели утешение в молитвах. Поэтому не следует путать такие дома с домом престарелых. В домах призрения трудились часто сестры милосердия — верующие люди, которые считали это богоугодным делом.